# JTextArea inside JScrollPane multiline

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have this code for show `JTextArea` inside

```
text = new JTextArea("");
    text.setRows(5);
    text.setColumns(50);
    JScrollPane scroll_pane = new JScrollPane(text, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Now I would that when cursor reach end of text area, it goes automatically to newline(the 50 columns). How can I do that?

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
text.setLineWrap(true);
```

Comment: See also [`setWrapStyleWord(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setWrapStyleWord-boolean-)..